# MS ACCESS Database Password - How secure?

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access, encryption, delphi-7

I have a program written in Delphi 7, which uses a MS Access 2000 database as the backend.

I have password protected my MS ACCESS 2000 Database file (*.mdb) with a 16 character password consisting of a misture of Numeral, control, UpperCase, and LowerCase characters.

However, it looks like there are a number of programs on the market that claim that the password can be retrieved.  What is the purpose of this database password if that is the case?  Is there anyway to make it so it is not retrievable?  Tighten the encryption so to speak?

thanks

Comment: Database passwords, particularly previous to the introduction of the ACCDB format in A2007, are basically useless (easily crackable and have to be embedded in your front end code) -- they are security theater, and there is no real reason to ever use them. If you need data security, you should be using a different database engine. Jet/ACE, because it's file-based and requires direct access by each user, can never really be secure.

Comment: BTW, why do you think you need to encrypt your database? If you really need to protect the data, then you've absolutely chosen the wrong data store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway to make it so it is
>   not retrievable? Tighten the
>   encryption so to speak?

It depends; you can either change your database and look for a more secure one (e.g. MS SQL Server Compact Edition), or if you want to stay on MS Access and security of the data is important to you, go for encrypting important fields using a good encryption algorithm (e.g. AES).

If you are going to encrypt your fields, you can do it transparently in Delphi; each DB field in Delphi is derived from TField class, and has two events called OnGetText and OnSetText. OnGetText is fired every time you try to read the field's data, and OnSetText is fired every time you try to write to the field. You can encrypt a field data whenever OnSetText is fired, that way, the encrypted data will be saved in the database. On the other hand, you can decrypt a field data whenever OnGetText is fired, that way, user will always see and work with the decrypted data. The whole process would be transparent to the users.

Of course you should take note that encrypting/ decrypting fields every time they are being read or write has performance drawback depending on number of fields to be encrypted, their size, frequency of reading or writing them, and the encryption algorithm which is used. It's better you just encrypt the important fields.

Another option could be to encrypt the whole MS Access database file, and decrypt it whenever your application is connecting to it, but that way, the file is secure as long as your application is not running; once your application is running and the file is decrypted; the file is exposed to others.

Comment: "Another option could be to encrypt the whole MS Access database file"  ?  Any suggestions i how i might go about this. Is there a free delphi encryption library for encrypting and decrypting large database files?

Comment: @Shane, encrypting the whole MS Access database file is just encrypting a file. To encrypt/ decrypt a file in Delphi, you have several free or commercial options. The two well-known free encryption libraries in Delphi are Delphi Encryption Compendium, and TurboPower LockBox. Another free option is using Windows cryptography API (Windows CryptoAPI).

Answer (score 4):

[MS Access 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-2010-security-HA010341741.aspx) uses better encryption and has some other features. [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) edition gives you a lot more security but is still appropriate for a desktop app.

Otherwise, go with a server database: mysql, sql server, oracle. Most have free versions.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into upgrading the Database to a newer version if the client accepts

Answer (score 2):

> What is the purpose of this database password if that is the case?

It makes people who think Access is a real database feel good about it.

> Is there anyway to make it so it is not retrievable?

Stop using Access.

> Tighten the encryption so to speak?

Not in Access.  However, if you stop using Access and use a real database, you'll find that you can also have real security.

Comment: Couldn't that get very expensive in training if the application is widely distributed?

Comment: 'What is the purpose of this database password if that is the case? Is there anyway to make it so it is not retrievable? Tighten the encryption so to speak?"  I don't believe you answered my quesions. Instead, you critize and put down the product. In addtion, you tell me to stop using it. I can't stop using it. It is not my choice.

Comment: @Shane: Here's the point.  The product doesn't do what you hope it should do.  What else can I say?  The product isn't very secure.  Use SQL/Server as the backend data repository with an MS-Access front-end.

Comment: @Remou: Not at all.  MS-Access can use SQL/Server and any ODBC database.  If you use a proper ODBC database as the backend with an MS-Access front-end you have security *and* usability.  No training change.  Also, your MS-Access "database" becomes very small, since it's only forms and reports and queries.  No actual data.

Comment: @S.Lott, he is developing in Deplhi, msaccess database is used only for data - your comment is out of context

Comment: What about maintenance of SQL server? It is not file based, so it is harder to set-up and maintain. Furthermore, as far as I can tell, the OP has an Access back-end, not a front-end. There is always a confusion with Access, because it is two products in one, the Jet/Ace side for data, and the Access side for forms, reports etc. You should never have the two in the one file, unless it is for one user, and even then a back-end / front-end set-up can be better.

Comment: @Remou: It is not file based, so it is **easier** to set-up and maintain.  According to some.

Comment: -1 for the insulting tone in regard to Access. You can say the same things without being a dick.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I'm open to suggestions.  They're more helpful than negativity.  Please suggest alternative wording.  I couldn't think of any.  Seriously.  The problem is well known.  I thought simple would be appropriate.  I see you disagree.  What would have been better?

Comment: Well, for starters, lose the phrase "people who think Access is a real database". Access's database engine, Jet/ACE, *is* a "real database," so getting rid of that blatant falsehood would be a good place to start.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: With no security, it's "real"?  I would have thought security was an element of providing real database services.  I guess I was wrong.  Why does every other database take security so seriously then?  What am I missing?  Is it because security isn't in Codd's 12 rules?

Comment: Who said Jet/ACE has "no security?" Nobody who knows what they are talking about. But what it provides is inadequate for certain levels of data security. If you're going to make wild claims about Jet/ACE not being a "real database" you'd better define "real database" when you make that assertion. Any file-based database engine will unquestionably fail to clear the high security bar you've set, so it's silly to make that the one aspect you use to determine "realness" in a database.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: "inadequate for certain levels of data security" is equivalent to no security in my book.  Once the data is compromised, it's compromised and there may as well have been no security at all.  By "Real Database" I mean one with actual security.  Oracle, DB2, MySQL and similar databases with proper password security leap to mind as examples of "Real Databases".  Perhaps you have others?

Comment: Collapsing all security requirements into a single level that you find acceptable is intellectually dishonest. You're starting with your conclusion ("Jet/ACE is not a real database") and working backwards from that. Discussion over, as you're not an honest debate partner.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: You're so right.  Simplification and summarization are "intellectually dishonest".  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

If security is a requirement then you should not be using a Jet database or any other file-sharing database architecture. It's as simple as that.

Comment: That is not an option! The question is : 'What is the purpose of this database password if that is the case? Is there anyway to make it so it is not retrievable? Tighten the encryption so to speak?"  I don't believe you answered my quesions.

Comment: So security is not an option for you. That's a pity. The purpose of the password is to provide the illusion of security for people who don't know better. Security by Obscurity basically.

Comment: Shane: The top post answers those. The purpose of the encryption is to give the illusion of security. In the same way you can kick open a door with a bad lock, you can crack MS Access security just as easily. There is no way to make it less retrievable. You cannot tighten the security. You have two options: 1) Stop using Access and move to a different database that is secure; 2) Give up on security as an option. There is no way to have strong security and use MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of this database
>   password if that is the case?

The purpose is to get people to upgrade to MS SQL Server and buy licenses for that as well. There are things MS will never fix.

On the other hand they have a free version of MS SQL Server which is not so crippled so you don't have to start paying through your nose unless your system will actually grow to need a full MS SQL Server.

However, if you develop systems like that (with no plan and not understanding limitations of the technologies you choose), you are most likely to lock yourself into proprietary features, for better or worse.

EDIT:
Here is quote directly from [MS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-2010-security-HA010341741.aspx#_Toc265079111)

> **Note**   Although the model and
>   techniques discussed in this article
>   enhance security, the most secure way
>   to help protect your Access data is to
>   store your tables on a server, such as
>   a computer running Windows SharePoint
>   Services 3.0 or Microsoft Office
>   SharePoint Server 2010.

Comment: I didn't choose the database. I am working on a program for someone else. Again, as the other two people before you, you did not answer the question, instead, you critize the vendor.

Comment: @Shane, sorry my aim was to explain the vendor's strategy in the last decade. Any file based DBMS will be inherently insecure compared to client server, and even though 2010 improves encryption, I would not bet own money on it. What is the reason you can not change the database? It might not be so complicated (problems should be on the level of http://www.i-logic.com/utilities/MySQL.htm)

Comment: Shane: stop being so defensive. He wasn't criticizing the vendor, he was merely pointing out the fact that there is no such thing as strong MS Access databases. Even Microsoft says so.

Answer (score 0):

Use crypt aes instead of standard mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

I posted this question on Experts-Exchange as well.  This is the kind of answer i was looking for (not critisism). Although this person eventually tells me to switch datbabases, he clearly explains why, without critisism:

DatabaseMX:

As you've discovered,  there is essentially no security in an Access db password, prior to A2007.  The are 1000's of tools (some free) that can immediately hack an Access password.  A2007/10 is using an improved password paradigm ... it's security level is not clear yet.

"Is there anyway to make it so it is not retrievable"
No.  It's only slightly better than nothing, depending on your specific environment where the mdb will be used.

"What is the purpose of this database password if that is the case? "
It was just a bad implementation. Period.

With A2003 and prior, the best you can do are a combination of the following:
1) db password
2) Add User Level Security
3) Create an MDE to protect code. But event an MDE can be hacked.

So, IF ... you really need better security, you will need to look at SQL Server or equivalent platform.

mx

Comment: Great, but there was no "criticism" in some of the replies you got here either. I didn't criticise anyone. Please accept one of the answers here.

Comment: This answer confuses data security with code protection in an Access front-end application. -1